# If $\sin(A) = \cos(A)$ find $2 \tan^2 A - 2 \sec^2 A + 5$

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

This is my first try to trigonometry, I have solved 100s of questions but this one always comes incorrect!

Can anyone help me?

Question:

If $\sin A = \cos A$, find the value of:

$2 \tan^2 A - 2 \sec^2 A + 5$

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint 1 : Since $\sin A$ and $\cos A$ are equal,

$$\tan A = \frac{\sin A}{\cos A} = 1$$

Hint 2 :

$$\sec^2 A = 1 + \tan^2 A$$

---

In fact, for any real values of $A$, we have $\tan^2 A - \sec^2 A = -1$ by rearranging the Pythagorean identity.

As such, the required result is $-2 + 5 = 3$ regardless of any constraint on $A$.

Comment: Sorry to ask but can you tell me how Hint 2 is derived?

Comment: It is part of the three Trigonometric Pythagorean Identites : Start with the well known $\sin^2 A + \cos^2 A = 1$ and divide throughout by $\cos^2 A$.

Comment: Probably due to the fact that I am in 9th standard, I am still not getting the answer.

Comment: $\sin^2 A + \cos^2 A = 1$ (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_trigonometric_identity) is a very important identity that should be in your syllabus by now.

Comment: At which step are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks for the Wikipedia link! Finally got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$2\tan^2(A)-2\sec^2(A)+5$$$$=2\frac{\sin^2(A)}{\cos^2(A)}-2\frac{1}{\cos^2(A)}+5$$$$=2\frac{\sin^2(A)-1}{\cos^2(A)}+5=-2+5=3$$

Comment: plus 5 not minus 5.